# Is there any way to show AM/PM in mysql now() function?

Tags: mysql, sql, time, datetime-format

I got these value `2017-11-10 14:07:24 000000` in my mysqli database field where i made a column named "`date`" with a "`datetime`" format and i set the maximum length to `6`.

How can i make it look like **`2017-11-10 14:07:00`** ?

and if there's any way I can get or covert this time to **`12 Hour`** format ?

Comment: You only ever do stuff between core hours 9-5?

Comment: I don’t understand. What’s ‘maximum length’ ?!?!?

Comment: Your example date isn't in 12 hour format.

Comment: I already said my example data isn't in 12 hour format , that's why i need to change it to 12 hour format. @HeikkiMäenpää

Comment: the maximum length is the total value of column , Do you get me ? @Strawberry

Comment: no. Sometimes i'm a night bird... It depends on situation, Cause i'm home learner. @P.Salmon

Comment: And why dont you guys give a upvote for my question ? I'm not eligible to get it from you ? :D

Comment: @LegendTariq No. In the context of a date data type, I don't know what that means. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You are asking how to make your data look like `2017-11-10 14:07:00`, which is in 24 hour format.

Comment: Yes.. In this condition i just want to delete or remove those 000000 from the first line..  @Haem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this to convert time to **12hr** format

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2017-11-10 14:07:00', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p')
```

More info about [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function and how to convert format of date.

Comment: Can you more specify ?